# Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL error

Tags: mysql, joomla

I just moved my server into website but I have this error even after I finished editing the `config.php` and I do not know why MySQL is still not connected :(

Please help me. All of my username passwords and hostname in DB are correct; but every since I carried out the aforementioned task all the user names and passwords are not being displayed (presumably lost).

```
<?php
class JConfig {
    public $offline = '0';
    public $offline_message = 'This site is down for maintenance.<br /> Please check back again soon.';
    public $display_offline_message = '1';
    public $offline_image = '';
    public $sitename = 'localhost';
    public $editor = 'jce';
    public $captcha = '0';
    public $list_limit = '20';
    public $access = '1';
    public $debug = '0';
    public $debug_lang = '0';
    public $dbtype = 'mysql';
    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $user = 'xxx';
    public $password = 'xxx';
    public $db = 'xxx';
    public $dbprefix = 'ocer4_';
    public $live_site = '';
    public $secret = '2PvZ36bJU5A7Iceo';
    public $gzip = '0';
    public $error_reporting = 'default';
    public $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help{major}{minor}:{keyref}';
    public $ftp_host = 'ftp.byethost13.com';
    public $ftp_port = '';
    public $ftp_user = 'b13_15953110';
    public $ftp_pass = '';
    public $ftp_root = '';
    public $ftp_enable = '0';
    public $offset = 'UTC';
    public $mailonline = '1';
    public $mailer = 'mail';
    public $mailfrom = 'tsukishiro_lee@yahoo.com';
    public $fromname = 'localhost';
    public $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
    public $smtpauth = '0';
    public $smtpuser = '';
    public $smtppass = '';
    public $smtphost = 'localhost';
    public $smtpsecure = 'none';
    public $smtpport = '25';
    public $caching = '0';
    public $cache_handler = 'file';
    public $cachetime = '15';
    public $MetaDesc = '';
    public $MetaKeys = '';
    public $MetaTitle = '1';
    public $MetaAuthor = '1';
    public $MetaVersion = '0';
    public $robots = '';
    public $sef = '1';
    public $sef_rewrite = '0';
    public $sef_suffix = '0';
    public $unicodeslugs = '0';
    public $feed_limit = '10';
    public $log_path = '/htdocs/logs';
    public $tmp_path = '/htdocs/tmp';
    public $lifetime = '15';
    public $session_handler = 'database';
    public $memcache_persist = '1';
    public $memcache_compress = '0';
    public $memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
    public $memcache_server_port = '11211';
    public $memcached_persist = '1';
    public $memcached_compress = '0';
    public $memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
    public $memcached_server_port = '11211';
    public $proxy_enable = '0';
    public $proxy_host = '';
    public $proxy_port = '';
    public $proxy_user = '';
    public $proxy_pass = '';
    public $MetaRights = '';
    public $sitename_pagetitles = '0';
    public $force_ssl = '0';
    public $session_memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
    public $session_memcache_server_port = '11211';
    public $session_memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
    public $session_memcached_server_port = '11211';
    public $frontediting = '1';
    public $feed_email = 'author';
    public $cookie_domain = '';
    public $cookie_path = '';
    public $asset_id = '1';
}
```

Comment: Is this Joomla?  If so, have you looked at https://docs.joomla.org/Unable_to_connect_to_the_database ?

Comment: yes and its still not working here is the code  (edited the post) i dont know how but in my account info the sql host name are not available :(. im only using free hosting account just for my project help me please @eggyal

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems the `$host = 'localhost'`.
I checked the config of your hosting and you should have as mysql host something like that `sqlxxx.byethost13.com` .

So update the `$host` variable as :

```
  public $host = "sqlxxx.byethost13.com";
```